# Vector space and its Projectivized Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, projective-space

Why is the co-dimension one subspaces are the points of $\mathbb P(V^{\vee})$.

$V^{\vee}$ is the dual space  of V and and $\mathbb P(V)$ is the projectivized space of V.

$\mathbb P(V)= \frac{V-\{0\}}{\sim}$ where $v_1 \sim v_2$ iff $\exists\lambda\in k$ s.t. $v_1=\lambda v_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codimension one subspaces are kernels of linear functionals uniquely defined up to scalars.

Comment: Ahh, correct. Thank you. May be to be precise  one should say kernels of non-zero functionals. Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$